# extract required directory name from a file path

Tags: python

I have the path-name of a file as follows:

```
fi = "http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TKC_/public_html/original/dc/dc_2008/dc_2008_141/dc_2008_141_0706+0900_TKC__y30_u.jpg"
```

How can I extract `"TKC_"` as the required information?

I tried as `print (os.path.basename(fi))` but it printed:

```
dc_2008_141_0706+0900_TKC__y30_u.jpg

"http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/**TKC_**/public_html/original/dc/dc_2008/dc_2008_141/dc_2008_141_0706+0900_TKC__y30_u.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

fi = "http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TKC_/public_html/original/dc/dc_2008/dc_2008_141/dc_2008_141_0706+0900_TKC__y30_u.jpg"
urlparse(fi).path.split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex:

```
import re
fi = "http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TKC_/public_html/original/dc/dc_2008/dc_2008_141/dc_2008_141_0706+0900_TKC__y30_u.jpg"
result = re.search(r'http://.*?/(.*?)/',fi)
print(result.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to define a pattern to search for in a string, which is `TKC_` in this case.

```
import re
fi = "http://pen.jamstec.go.jp/TKC_/public_html/original/dc/dc_2008/dc_2008_141/dc_2008_141_0706+0900_TKC__y30_u.jpg"
httpObj = re.compile(r'TKC_') # pattern to search for in the string
print(httpObj.findall(fi)[0])
```

If you remove `[0]` in the `print()` statement it will get you a list of all occurrences of `TKC_` in the string.